# Product of absolute values of eigenvalues of a function of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, permanent

Suppose I have a $2N\times 2N$ matrix $X$ with the first half of the (real) eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ positive and the latter half negative. I want to compute
$$P = f(\lambda_1)...f(\lambda_N)f(-\lambda_{N+1})...f(-\lambda_{2N})$$
if I didn't have the signs (or if $f$ was even etc), this would be $\det(f(X))$.

Is there any simple way to express this product, perhaps using permanents or Pfaffians?

Another way to state the above, which might help: suppose $X=S^{-1}\Lambda S$ with $\Lambda={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\dots \lambda_{2N})$. Then what I am after is any way to express

$$ \det f(gSXS^{-1}) $$
where
$$ g = {\rm diag}(\overbrace{1,1,\dots}^{N},\overbrace{-1,,\dots ,-1}^{N})$$
without making direct reference to $S$ - ie I'd like to not have to actually have diagonalised $X$ if at all possible.

Comment: When you call these eigenvalues "positive" and "negative", are you implying that all eigenvalues of $X$ are real?

Comment: How about $\sqrt{\det(X^*X)}$ (or $\sqrt{\det(X^TX)}$ if $X$ has real entries)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, real eigenvalues (but $X$ need not be hermitian, it may have non-orthogonal eigenvectors). I can only see that suggestion works if $f$ is the identity in which case I could more easily just take $(-1)^N\det(X)$.

Comment: My first instinct would not be to use permanents or Pfaffians, which are not preserved by similarity of matrices.

Comment: The reason why determinants are related to eigenvalues in the first place is that similar matrices have the same determinant

Comment: Can one even deal with the case of $f(t)=t+1$ and $N=1,N=2$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician you can brute force it since the function I wrote does only depend on the spectrum. For $f(t)=t+1$ and $N=1$ you can find $P=1+\sqrt{{\rm Tr}(x)^2-4\det(x)}-\det(X)$. Of course, it's not obvious how to do this for arbitrary $f$, and the result doesn't have much resemblence to $t+1$.

Comment: Yes, that's the best I could do, but I couldn't get anything similar for $N=2$.